# How can i only get the body contents of easyAdmin bundle twigs

Tags: symfony, twig, easyadmin

I want the functionality of EasyAdmin Bundle but i just want the body tag cause i have my own template and i can't seem to be able to extract only the contents of the body tag.

i tried the checking out the code but it keeps referencing other twigs
i just want what's inside the body block in html and css

```
{% extends 'baseback.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}


{% endblock %}
```

[image]

this is what i need from the bundle code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the EasyAdmin source code:

https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/src/Resources/views/default/layout.html.twig

You can see that `body` block contains everything including menus and stuff; where  `content` block is what you want.

Now in the documentation:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#overriding-the-default-templates-using-symfony-s-mechanism

You can override the above `layout.html.twig` in your own project to only render what you want.